# invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct arr')

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct arr{
    int *temp;
    int size;
}*var;

void inputArray(int);
void displayArray(int);

int main()
{

    int cases,i;
    printf("Enter the no of test cases\n");
    scanf("%d",&cases);
    for(i=0;i<cases;++i)
    {
        printf("Entering test case %d:\n\n",i+1);
        inputArray(i);
    }
    printf("You have entered the following\n");
    for(i=0;i<cases;++i)
    {
        printf("Test case %d\n\n",i+1);
        displayArray(i);
    }
    return 0;
}

void inputArray(int count)
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d",&(var+count)->size);
    (var+count)->temp=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(var+count)->size);
    if((var+count)->temp==NULL)
    {
        printf("NOT ENOUGH MEMORY IN HEAP");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter the array\n");
    for(i=0;i<(var+count)->size;++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &(var+count)->temp[i] );
    }

}

void displayArray(int count)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<(var+count)->size;++i)
    {
        printf(" %d ",(var+count)->temp[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

In the above code, whenever I replace 
`(var+count)->`...  with `var[count]->` it shows the error :" invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct arr') "
but there is no problem when I use either `temp[i]` or `temp+i`.
Both `var` and `temp` are pointers. So why do I get this error ?

Another unrelated question, where or when do I have to free the dynamically allocated pointer `temp`. `temp` was dynamically allocated inside the function `void inputArray(int);` which is called in a loop in main.

Comment: The compilation error aside, in either case, you are never assigning any value to `var`, so you are not allowed to dereference it as you do. Your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: First of all, the global pointer variable `var` is `NULL` since it hasn't been explicitly initialized, it has been "tentatively defined" with a default initial value `NULL`.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add `var=(struct arr*)malloc(sizeof(struct arr)*cases);`

Comment: You cannot store data in allocated memory before you have actually allocated that memory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(var+count)` **!=** `var[count]` but

`*(var+count)` **==** `var[count]`

and because

`(*(var+count)).temp` or `(var+count)-> temp` then

`var[count].temp` or `(&var[count]) -> temp`

**MAKE SURE** `var` is properly initialized and is referencing a valid object before using it!!

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that OP's `var` isn't pointing to anything. It will be `NULL`.

Comment: I just abstract from this code as OP does not understand how pointers and arrays work. So this very quick example.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add `var=(struct arr*)malloc(sizeof(struct arr)*cases);`

Comment: @P__J__ You answer does not make sense. It is irrelevant.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow your comment does not make any sense `In the above code, whenever I replace (var+count)->... with var[count]-> it shows the error :" invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct arr') "`

Comment: @P__J__ Well, o'k.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow all other answers are irrelevant. Aren't they?

Comment: @P__J__  Another unrelated question, where or when do I have to free the dynamically allocated pointer temp. temp was dynamically allocated inside the function void inputArray(int); which is called in a loop in main.

Comment: @VinodAntony when is not needed anymore

Answer (score 1):

The declared pointer with the static storage duration

```
struct arr{
    int *temp;
    int size;
}*var;
```

is zero-initialized and does not point to any allocated memory.

So your program has undefined behavior.

At least you need to allocated an array of the type `struct arr` with cases `elements` before calling the functions.

For example

```
var = malloc( cases * sizeof( struct arr ) );
```

As for the question

> In the above code, whenever I replace (var+count)->... with
>   var[count]-> it shows the error :" invalid type argument of '->

then the expression `var[count]` is not a pointer. It has the type `struct arr`.

Here a demonstrative program that shows how the assignment can be implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct arr
{
    int *temp;
    size_t size;
};

void inputArray( struct arr *var, size_t count )
{
    printf( "Enter the size of the array: " );

    size_t n = 0;

    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    ( var + count )->temp = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( ( var + count )->temp == NULL )
    {
        ( var + count )->size = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ( var + count )->size = n;

        if ( n != 0 )
        {
            printf( "Enter %zu element(s) of the array: ", n );
            for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i )
            {
                scanf( "%d", &( var + count)->temp[i] );
            }
        }           
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}

void displayArray( const struct arr *var, size_t count )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < ( var + count )->size; ++i )
    {
        printf( "%d ", ( var+count )->temp[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "Enter the no of test cases: " );

    size_t n = 0;

    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    struct arr *var = malloc( n * sizeof( struct arr ) );

    if ( var == NULL ) 
    {
        puts( "Error. Not enough memory." );
        n = 0;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "Entering test case %zu:\n", i+1 );
        inputArray( var, i );
    }

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        puts( "You have entered the following" );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        {
            printf("Test case %zu:" ,i + 1 );
            displayArray( var, i );
        }

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        {
            free( ( var + i )->temp );
        }
    }

    free( var );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter the no of test cases: 5
Entering test case 1:
Enter the size of the array: 1
Enter 1 element(s) of the array: 1
Entering test case 2:
Enter the size of the array: 2
Enter 2 element(s) of the array: 1 2
Entering test case 3:
Enter the size of the array: 3
Enter 3 element(s) of the array: 1 2 3
Entering test case 4:
Enter the size of the array: 4
Enter 4 element(s) of the array: 1 2 3 4
Entering test case 5:
Enter the size of the array: 5
Enter 5 element(s) of the array: 1 2 3 4 5
You have entered the following
Test case 1:1 
Test case 2:1 2 
Test case 3:1 2 3 
Test case 4:1 2 3 4 
Test case 5:1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: My bad, I understand now.. can you help me with this ?
"Another unrelated question, where or when do I have to free the dynamically allocated pointer temp. temp was dynamically allocated inside the function void inputArray(int); which is called in a loop in main." @Vlad from Moscow

Comment: He is not asking about it. `In the above code, whenever I replace (var+count)->... with var[count]-> it shows the error :" invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct arr') "`